# Gratis interactive transcript API

Tags: gratis, video, api, transcription

I am looking for an interactive transcript API that is available for free/open source and **usable for commercial websites**.

Here are a few examples of the same:

- [JWPlayer](http://www.jwplayer.com/)
- [CaptionBox](http://speakertext.com/captionbox)

Any recommendations/suggestions are very much welcome.